# How to mock varible inside a method

Tags: python, methods, mocking

I want to mock variable inside a method

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self,ip,port,username,password):
        self.__ip=ip
        self.__port=port
        self.__username=username
        self.__password=password
        self.__connected=False

    def connect():
        if self.__connected:
           return RET_SUCCESS
```

I want to reach return statement buy mocking varible inside `connect()` method.
In this case, if I make `self__connected = True` then only it will reach the return statement. How to mock variables inside method?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the instance variable directly. Since you're using double underscores, the property would be accessible as:

```
instance._a__connected = False
```

You can also mock the method to return that value directly:

```
with patch.object(a, 'connect', return_value=RET_SUCCESS) as mock_method:
    instance = a()
    instance.connect()
```